# How to determine cause for Android crash?

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a certain word to search in Logcat that will give me the specific reason for the crash?

Otherwise I'm scrolling through hundreds of logs and only 1 of them is important to determine the reason for the crash.

Comment: select error in logcat !

Comment: use crash lythices for cash report.

Comment: Some info: [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors).

Answer (score 0):

Most of android crash reports start with `FATAL EXCEPTION` and then followed by `Process: your.application.package, PID: yourAppPID`.

You can also use tools like Fabric's Crashlytics to have your crash reports organized in a web browser.